# How to make a bot that reads how many times a message has been written in a text channel using discord.py?

Tags: python, search, bots, discord.py, history

*This is my code:*
(I use python 3.7)

```
    import discord
    import random
    import json
    import asyncio
    from importlib import import_module
    from importlib import reload


    class MyClient(discord.Client):
        async def on_ready(self):
            print('Logged in as')
            print(self.user.name)
            print(self.user.id)
            print('------')
            activity = discord.Activity(name='for someone to hug!', type=discord.ActivityType.watching)
            await client.change_presence(activity=activity)

        async def on_message(self, message):
            # we do not want the bot to reply to itself
            if message.author.id == self.user.id:
                return

            with open("Bobby\code\Bobby\json\on_message.json") as json_file:
                data = json.load(json_file)
                for key in data["command"]: 
                    with open("Bobby\code\Bobby\json\settings.json") as json_file2:
                        data2 = json.load(json_file2)
                        cmd = data2["settings"]["prefix"]+key  
                    if message.content.startswith(cmd):
                        counter = 0
                        async for msg in client.logs_from(message.channel, limit=500):
                            await asyncio.sleep(3)
                            if msg.content.lower() == message.content.lower():
                                counter = counter + 1
                        result = "" + counter
                        await message.channel.send(result)   
                else:
                    for key in data["message"]: 
                        if key in message.content.lower():
                            counter = 0
                            for key2 in data["message"][""+key+""]:
                                if key2 == "channel":
                                    counter = counter + 1
                                    channel = client.get_channel(data["message"][""+key+""]["channel"])
                                    await channel.send(random.choice(data["message"][""+key+""]["messages"]))
                            if counter == 0:
                                await message.channel.send(random.choice(data["message"][""+key+""]["messages"]))



    client = MyClient()
    client.run('my token')
```

I tried all my project and I know that everything works except this part:

```
   async for msg in client.logs_from(message.channel, limit=500):
       await asyncio.sleep(3)
       if msg.content.lower() == message.content.lower():
           counter = counter + 1
   result = "" + counter
```

I don't understand how to work with **logs_from**, I also tried to use **message.channel.history** like this:

```
   counter = 0
   async for m in message.channel.history(limit=500):
       await asyncio.sleep(3)
       if message.content.lower() == m.content.lower():
           counter = counter + 1
   result = "" + counter
```

Also how I can search in **all** the history of the text channel?

I guess I'm failing something about the use of *await* and *async*, does someone have some suggestions to give me to solve this problem? Should I use a different approach to achieve this?

Comment: Why do you have that 3 second wait for every message in the history?  That's going to take hours to run.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh I added that just after few tries because I wanted to see if logs_from needed more time to operate, but even without that It wasn't working still

Comment: What exactly is the error message you get?  At a glance, `result = "" + counter` is also going to cause problems, you should do `result = str(counter)` instead

Comment: By changing `result = "" + counter` to `result = str(counter)` and I removed `await asyncio.sleep(3)` as you suggested + I changed the condition inside the message.channel.history() loop and now it works perfectly. thank you @PatrickHaugh